# How to dispose RestClient from RestSharp

Tags: .net, restsharp

Hi I am using RestClient from RestSharp nuget package, but I found it does not implement IDisposable. So do I need to dispose it or how to dispose it?

The example codes are from Mailgun api:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient ();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri ("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");
        client.Authenticator =
            new HttpBasicAuthenticator ("api",
                                        "YOUR_API_KEY");
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest ();
        request.AddParameter ("domain", "YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        request.Resource = "{domain}/messages.mime";
        request.AddParameter ("to", "bar@example.com");
        request.AddFile ("message", Path.Combine ("files", "message.mime"));
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        return client.Execute (request);
```

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907879/dispose-object-of-restrequest-restsharp)?

Comment: There is nothing to explicitly dispose. Garbage collector will take care of freeing resources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dispose Object Of RestRequest RestSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907879/dispose-object-of-restrequest-restsharp)

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of RestClient support dispose method. Use `using` block or call `client.Dispose()` in finally block. you can also pass httpclient during initialization for restclient and maintain as per your needs.